# Why is the textArea not aligning properly with a drop down menu?

Tags: css

I have 4 divs inside a div

```
<div style="margin: 30px;">
   <div class="awmDiv">Here you have the drop down menu</div>
   <div class="awmDiv">Some Text</div>
   <div class="awmDiv">Here is the textarea</div>
   <div class="awmDiv">Buttons</div>
</div>
```

Each of these child divs have:

```
.awmDiv {
    width: 40%;
    /* background-color: orange; */
}
```

and the textarea and drop down menu components occupy:

```
.awmDivComps {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now looking at the image:
[image]

Why are the `drop down menu` and `textarea` fields not in line with one another and how to align them properly?

Comment: Your markup doesn't have a textarea.

Comment: @canon:I have mentioned it by the text.

Comment: It does seem that they are aligned, don't they? Only the padding on the dropdown is a bit higher ...

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari it's generally helpful to include a minimal example. Excluding the very elements you're asking about doesn't help anyone help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having a box model issue. Try `box-sizing: border-box`:

```css
.awmDiv {
  width: 40%;
}
.awmDivComps {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 30px;">
  <div class="awmDiv">
    <select class="awmDivComps"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="awmDiv">
    <textarea class="awmDivComps"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```